# Visual Studio Code - How to permanently disable the left side bar?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Using Visual Studio Code version 1.44.0, how do I permanently disable the left side bar?  I hit control + B to hide it, but every time I hit F5, it comes back up.  How do I make it not come up when I hit F5 to run the code?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting:

> Debug: Open Debug

set it to `never`.  Default is `openOnSessionStart`

Comment: Thank you @Mark!  I hope you have a blessed day and are doing well through all the stuff going on.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a visual and a step-by-step of Mark's answer: Thanks Mark!

- File > Preferences > Settings > type debug:open > select 'neverOpen' from the drop-down.

[image]